# How to move a single row from one pandas dataframe to another with an impure function?

Tags: python, pandas, function

So I have have written a short function that basically moves a single row, based on the index, from one dataframe to another, while preserving the index.

If I have this test dataframe and an empty one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lower': ['a','b','c'],
                   'upper': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'number': [1, 2, 3]},
                  index=['first', 'second', 'third'])
print(df, '\n\n')

empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lower', 'upper', 'number'])
print(empty, '\n\n')
```

and I just use the instructions:

```
line = 'second'
empty = empty.append(df.loc[line])
df = df.drop(index=line)
```

it works.

But if I try to write an impure function that does the same thing, it only modifies the dataframes inside the function, and outside it they remain unchanged!?

Here is my entire code:

```
def move_line(ind, source, destination):
    row = source.loc[ind]
    destination = destination.append(row)
    source = source.drop(index=ind)
    print('source inside function\n', source, '\n\n')
    print('destination inside function\n', destination, '\n\n')


def main():

    df = pd.DataFrame({'lower': ['a','b','c'],
                       'upper': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                       'number': [1, 2, 3]},
                      index=['first', 'second', 'third'])
    #print(df, '\n\n')

    empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lower', 'upper', 'number'])
    #print(empty, '\n\n')


    move_line('second', df, empty)

    print('source outside function\n', df, '\n\n')
    print('destination outside function\n', empty)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it only modifies the dataframes inside the function, and outside it they remain unchanged!?

That is because `DataFrame.append` doesn't mutate the original DataFrame, it creates a new DataFrame with the new row. The original object is left unchanged. `DataFrame.drop` by default also doesn't change the original object, unless you pass `inplace=True`.

> ```
> destination = destination.append(row)
> source = source.drop(index=ind)
> ```

Here you are only rebinding the names `destination` and `source` to the objects returned by `append` and `drop`, they are not the same original objects which `destination` and `source` originally pointed to. The original objects remain unchanged.

To mutate the original objects you can do the following

```
def move_line(ind, source, destination):
    row = source.loc[ind]
    destination.loc[ind] = row 
    source.drop(index=ind, inplace=True)
    print('source inside function\n', source, '\n\n')
    print('destination inside function\n', destination, '\n\n')
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lower': ['a','b','c'],
                   'upper': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'number': [1, 2, 3]},
                  index=['first', 'second', 'third'])
#print(df, '\n\n')

empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lower', 'upper', 'number'])
#print(empty, '\n\n')


move_line('second', df, empty)

print('source outside function\n', df, '\n\n')
print('destination outside function\n', empty)
```

Output:

```
source inside function
       lower upper  number
first     a     A       1
third     c     C       3 


destination inside function
        lower upper number
second     b     B      2 


source outside function
       lower upper  number
first     a     A       1
third     c     C       3 


destination outside function
        lower upper number
second     b     B      2
```